# How I can flatten a tree in an orderly way?

Tags: php, recursion, tree

I have PHP array (tree), something like this:

```
$categoryTree = [
    0 => [
        'id' => 1360,
        'parent' => 0,
        'name' => 'main A',
        'children' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 1361,
                'parent' => 1360,
                'name' => 'sub a1'
            ],
            1 => [
                'id' => 57,
                'parent' => 1360,
                'name' => 'sub a2'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    1 => [
        'id' => 10,
        'parent' => 0,
        'name' => 'Main B'
    ]
];
```

I want to convert it into:

```
$categoryTree = [
    0 => [
        'id' => 1360,
        'parent' => 0,
        'name' => 'main A'
    ],
    1 => [
        'id' => 1361,
        'parent' => 1360,
        'name' => 'sub a1'
    ],
    2 => [
        'id' => 57,
        'parent' => 1360,
        'name' => 'sub a2'
    ],
    3 => [
        'id' => 10,
        'parent' => 0,
        'name' => 'Main B'
    ]
];
```

Comment: Please share your tried code.

Comment: @Rikesh I wasn't able to think on how to walk recursively and keep adding the feels without loosing them.

Comment: @Rikesh, the closest thing I was able to write is `array_walk_recursive($categoryTree, function ($item, $key) use (&$categoryNames) {if ($key === 'name') {$categoryNames[] = $item;}});print_r($categoryNames);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rather simple. You walk recursively and *only* make a recursive call if the node has the key `children`. During the iteration in the foreach loop, keep collecting results in an result array.

```
<?php

function flatten($tree, &$results){
    foreach($tree as $kid){
        $kid_copy = $kid;
        unset($kid_copy['children']);
        $results[] = $kid_copy;
        if(isset($kid['children'])) flatten($kid['children'], $results);
    }
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/e4a34)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, using a generator,  which then doesn't need the second argument:

```
function recurIter($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        $orig = $item;
        unset($item["children"]);
        yield $item;
        if (isset($orig["children"])) yield from recurIter($orig["children"]);
    }
}

$result = iterator_to_array(recurIter($categoryTree), false);
```